# Bootable partition is not shown in the boot picker or the BIOS

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, grub2, boot-partition

So i couldn’t find my USB drive anywhere, and i thought i’d install Linux from my internal hard drive. Created a new partition, formatted as FAT32, and `dd`-ed the image onto it.

I rebooted, and the partition wasn’t showing up in the BIOS. The logical thing to do was boot back into my functional installation and boot off of the new partition with `qemu`. This worked.

It was a little bit weird, but I just moved on. I went to the grub config and manually added a new entry that would set the correct root, kernel and initrd. I rebooted, and selected the new GRUB option. It worked.

I got to installing it, and it failed at some point, it couldn’t unmount `/cdrom`. Okay, well i can just launch a terminal and do it myself, right? I did, and after killing `ubiquity` I instantly got dropped into the live env. Fair enough. I relaunched ubiquity from the terminal (as root) and it started doing its thing.

At some point though, it said it failed to install the bootloader. That was weird. Things started going downhill from here.

I then restarted the installation, thinking it was a small problem, but it did it again. So I `chroot` -ed into `/target` (the mount point of the installed system), and tried to run `grub-install` myself.

It started saying something about `/dev` not being mounted and stuff, so i kinda just tried formatting `/dev/sda1`, the installed system, to maybe get ubiquity to try again fresh. That didn’t work, I wasn’t able to format it.

Fair enough, i tinkered a lot with them. I tried ubiquity once more and got a little further (or so i thought). It said it can’t wipe the disk since it can’t notify the kernel about the new partitions. I needed to reboot.

Dang it. Now keep in mind, the first time I ran ubiquity it actually got far enough to wipe my disk. I didn’t have grub installed anymore.

I tried some more things, but nothing worked. Finally, i thought that maybe the BIOS would recognize my partition. So I quickly installed qemu on the live env. and booted from the partition with the image. It worked.

The only thing left to do was reboot, i guess. I rebooted, and nope. It couldn’t see it.

So now i’m stuck in the BIOS with nothing else to do. I could buy a USB drive, but i really want to sort this out like this.

So yeah, `/dev/sda3` has a Linux installer and i can’t boot from it.